# Skipping TURN server because of address type mis-match

Tags: firefox, proxy, webrtc, turn

I recently started investigating why some of the WebRTC connection in our application are failing in corporate environment. It has certainly something to do with the proxy/firewall settings as in normal/open environment everything works OK.

I started to watch the about:webrtc in Firefox logs and I noticed message, for which there is no explanation anywhere in the internet: "Skipping TURN server because of address type mis-match"

What does it mean? It sounds like potential reason for our corporate network issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That message comes from here in the source code:
https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/media/webrtc/transport/third_party/nICEr/src/ice/ice_component.c#299

It means that connecting to your turn is not possible because of an address type mismatch, i.e. you are trying to connect to an IPv4 only TURN server from an IPv6 interface. This would not work so Firefox is not even trying.

Check whether your TURN server supports IPv6 and whether the host candidates you get are ipv6-only.

Answer (score 0):

While you create RtcPeerConnection you should pass iceServer configuration. in production enviornment turn server is required because some peer might behind NAT , so this is mnadatory in this case.

more about ice Candidate types

**host**

A host candidate is one for which its ip address is the actual, direct IP address of the remote peer.

**prflx**

A peer reflexive candidate is one whose IP address comes from a symmetric NAT between the two peers, usually as an additional candidate during trickle ICE (that is, additional candidate exchanges that occur after primary signaling but before the connection verification phase is finished).

**srflx**

A server reflexive candidate is generated by a STUN/TURN server; the connection's initiator requests a candidate from the STUN server, which forwards the request through the remote peer's NAT, which creates and returns a candidate whose IP address is local to the remote peer. The STUN server then replies to the initiator's request with a candidate whose IP address is unrelated to the remote peer.

**relay**

A relay candidate is generated just like a server reflexive candidate ("srflx"), but using TURN instead of STUN.

check these links
[Link 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/TURN)

[link 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Connectivity)

[link 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceServer/urls)